# How to terminate cocoa app in applicationWillFinishLaunching delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsapplication

I have to show the custom license Agreement dialog to the user before they start using my application.So, I have added new window in my mainMenu.xib and showing that window modally using

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:licenseWindow];
```

in applicationWillFinishLaunching: delegate by making my main window hidden using visible at Launch to unchecked. License window has two buttons Agree and Disagree. I need to show the mainwindow if user clicks on Agree button and terminate the app if they choose Disagree.

I try to call [NSApp terminate]; in applicationWillFinishLaunching: but it didn't do anything.

Please let me know how I can terminate the app in applicationWillFinishLaunching:

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I found the solution myself. It was my mistake, I need to call [NSApp terminate:nil]; instead of [NSApp terminate]; and now I am able to terminate my app normally as needed.

Comment: Read the link I gave you too, it might save your app from being rejected by Apple.

Comment: **NSApp**, i.e. Mac OS, not iPhone OS.